# Merge 2 woocommerce product queries

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', array($this, 'b2bking_hide_products_category_visibility') );



function b2bking_hide_products_category_visibility($q ){

        $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
        $tax_query[] = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
               'field' => 'slug',
               'terms' => $visiblecategories, 
               'operator' => 'IN'
        );
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

        // Set query to only select products that are in "default" category mode, not manual visibility mode
        $q->set('meta_query', array(
                array(
                    'key'   => 'b2bking_product_visibility_override',
                    'value' => 'default',
                )
            ));



        /* SEPARATE META QUERY 
        $q->set('meta_query', array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'b2bking_group_'.$currentusergroupidnr,
                            'value' => '1'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'b2bking_user_'.$currentuserlogin,
                            'value' => '1'
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'b2bking_product_visibility_override',
                        'value' => 'manual',
                    )
                ));
        */


            }
        }
```

I currently have **(tax query AND meta query)**

I would like to have **(tax query AND meta query) OR (separate meta query)**

How can I achieve this? Can it be done within the "woocommerce_product_query" action? If so, what is the right syntax?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

You use

```
$q->set('post__in', $postIDs);
```

This makes WooCommerce show the exact array of products in the $postIDs array;

The final code looks like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', array($this, 'your_product_function') );
function your_product_function(){
            /* MAKE YOUR 2 CUSTOM PRODUCT QUERIES AS WP QUERIES */
            $queryA = new WP_Query($queryAparams);
            $queryB = new WP_Query($queryBparams);

            $postIDs= array_merge($queryA->posts,$queryB->posts);

          /* IMPORTANT, if the ARRAY is EMPTY, ALL PRODUCTS WILL BE SHOWN. A quick bypass is to pass an array of invalid ids as you can see below */
            if(!empty($allTheIDs)){
                $q->set('post__in',$postIDs);
            } else {
                $q->set('post__in',array('invalidid'));
            }

}
```

Very important is to pass 'fields'->'ids' in the parameters to get only IDs
this is how the individual queries look like

```
$queryBparams = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'fields' => 'ids',
                'meta_query'=> array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                'key' => 'b2bking_group_'.$currentusergroupidnr,
                                'value' => '1'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'b2bking_user_'.$currentuserlogin,
                                'value' => '1'
                            )
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'b2bking_product_visibility_override',
                            'value' => 'manual',
                        )
                    ));
```